# Django filter Two Models for ID

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django Application where registered users can be added Deposit by staff users, and I want to know whether a user has been added Deposit in the current month. And also check in HTML on a Button url whether the user has a deposit or Not then decide whether to display the Button or Not.

I have tried with the below code but here is the error I am getting: `Cannot use QuerySet for "Account": Use a QuerySet for "Profile".` And even when I use a queryset for Profile `customer_profile = Profile.objects.all()` it still says I should use queryset for User so  I am confused.
Here is my Models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    othernames = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)

    image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', blank=False, null=False, upload_to ='profile_images', 

)


#Method to save Image
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
#Check for Image Height and Width then resize it then save
        if img.height > 200 or img.width > 150:
            output_size = (150, 250)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
        



    def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.customer.username}-Profile'

class Account(models.Model):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return f' {self.customer} - Account No: {self.account_number}'

class Deposit(models.Model): 
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    transID = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    acct = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True) 
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('create_account', args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer} Deposited {self.deposit_amount} by {self.staff.username}'
```

Here is my View function:

```
def create_account(request): 
    customer = Account.objects.all()
   
    deposited_this_month = Deposit.objects.filter(customer__profile=customer, date__year=now.year, date__month=now.month).aggregate(deposited_this_month=Sum('deposit_amount')).get('deposited_this_month') or 0

 context = {
        
        'deposited_this_month ':deposited_this_month ,
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/customers.html', context)
```

In my HTML below is my code:

```
{% if deposited_this_month  %}

                  

                  <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="{% url 'account-statement' customer.id %}">Statement</a>

                  
                  {% else %}
                  
                  <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="">No Transaction</a>
                  
                  {% endif %}
```

Comment: provide the `Profile` model code

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access "profile" field using the "customer__profile" lookup, but "customer" field in the "Deposit" model is related to the "Profile" model, and "Profile" model doesn't have any profile field

Here is the updated version

and It would be better if you set `User` as foreign key for customer field in Deposit model.

```py
def create_account(request): 
    filtered_users = User.objects.all()

    filtered_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(customer__in=filtered_users)

    deposited_this_month = Deposit.objects.filter(customer__in=filtered_profiles, date__year=now.year, date__month=now.month).aggregate(deposited_this_month=Sum('deposit_amount')).get('deposited_this_month') or 0

    context = {
        'deposited_this_month': deposited_this_month,
    }

    return render(request, 'dashboard/customers.html', context)
```

Comment: your answer throws this error: **Cannot use QuerySet for "Account": Use a QuerySet for "Profile".**

Comment: updated answer based on the models you've provided

Comment: Sir, understand that I am not interested in getting the logged in user but I want to check whether the listed customers have made deposit or not and not the logged in Staff user. From your last answer I would be getting result for the logged in user and not from the list.

Comment: Updated the answer, and It would be better if you set `User` as a foreign key for the customer field in the Deposit model.